# ASP Net Core MVC Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code and it works perfectly fine until I add the last property in the js object

JS:

```
var serializableFilter = {};

serializableFilter.aosType = filter.aos.type;
serializableFilter.aosText = filter.aos.text;
serializableFilter.industries = filter.industries.getCommaSeperatedIDs();
serializableFilter.servicingBanks = filter.servicingBanks.getCommaSeperatedIDs();
serializableFilter.category = filter.categories.categoryID;
serializableFilter.yearEstablishedFrom = filter.yearEstablished.from;
serializableFilter.yearEstablishedTo = filter.yearEstablished.to;
serializableFilter.staffMin = filter.nbStaff.min;
serializableFilter.staffMax = filter.nbStaff.max;
//serializableFilter.includeBranches = filter.includeBranches;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(serializableFilter),
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IEnumerable<FdxxxMap>> GetC([FromBody] Filter data)
```

Model:

```
public class Filter
{
    public string aosType { get; set; }
    public string aosText { get; set; }
    public string industries { get; set; }
    public string servicingBanks { get; set; }
    public int category { get; set; }
    public int yearEstablishedFrom { get; set; }
    public int yearEstablishedTo { get; set; }
    public int staffMin { get; set; }
    public int staffMax { get; set; }
    public Boolean includeBranches { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I add the last property of type boolean, the data model is passed as null

Comment: do you get any errors in your browser console? also you dont have to use stringify, you are passing json

Comment: @N.Ivanov No, just a null model server side

Comment: do a `console.log(serializableFilter)` before the ajax, and see if everything looks fine

Comment: check value of `filter.includeBranches` maybe its something else so c# cant translate it to boolean

Comment: Everything looks fine. The is the stringified output `{"aosType":"circle","aosText":"33.882672291172085,35.518691539764404,2613.615443717917","industries":"","servicingBanks":"","category":0,"yearEstablishedFrom":1800,"yearEstablishedTo":2050,"staffMin":0,"staffMaxx":99999999999,"includeBranches":true}`

Comment: open dev-tools of your browser and check the request that was sent to the server. If the request is ok, your server is doing something wrong

Comment: @JohnnyAW The request is OK, the issue is with binding

Comment: my advice is: remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` entirely. MVC finds it easier to accept normal form data. Then just do `data: serializableFilter,` If that doesn't work try `data: { "data": serializableFilter },`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the type of filter.includeBranches is really bool.
Why wouldn't you try this:

```
serializableFilter.includeBranches = filter.includeBranches==true;
```

Comment: This is how it is being filled out `filter.includeBranches = document.getElementById('option-branches').checked`